# How to change `sourceMappingURL` by using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, cdn, source-maps, uglifyjs

My production webpack configuration is:

```
{
  output: {
    publicPath: "https://cdn.example.com/sub-directory/",
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].min.js'
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Now I have two files `app-12345.min.js` and `app-12345.min.js.map`.

I also have automatically generated CDN URL `https://cdn.example.com/sub-directory/app-12345.min.js` for main script.

But `sourceMappingURL` is still relative path `//# sourceMappingURL=app-12345.min.js.map` and not accessible directly in browser.

My question is how I can set `sourceMappingURL` as absolute automatically generated path?

Comment: did you find a solution to this, im facing the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally this is possible in **Webpack 3** using guide from the [@omj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947655/ornj)'s response and following configuration

```
  devtool: 'hidden-source-map', // SourceMap without reference in original file

  new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: '[file].map',
    append: `\n//# sourceMappingURL=${path}[url]`
  })
```

---

**Update (Webpack v3.10.0):**

A new option has been added since Webpack `v3.10.0`. The option called [`publicPath`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/1707/files):

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: '[file].map',
  publicPath: 'https://example.com/dev/'
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#sourcemapdevtoolplugin) plugin is an option.

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: '[file].map',
    append: '\n//# sourceMappingURL=' + path + '[url]'
});
```

Comment: Resulted file will contain two `sourceMappingURL` strings in this case.

`//# sourceMappingURL=https://example.com/app.js.map` and `//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map`

Comment: to fix this use `config.devtool = 'hidden-source-map'` then `append: ...`

Answer (score 6):

Note the devtool: false. You need that if you want to provide custom values. 
This works for webpack 4.x:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devtool: false,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
       filename: 'sourcemaps/[file].map',
       publicPath: 'https://example.com/project/',
       fileContext: 'public'
  })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With Webpack 2 you can use hidden-source-map for devtool and banner-webpack-plugin
from https://github.com/lcxfs1991/banner-webpack-plugin 
and set something like this:

```
new banner({
    chunks: {
        "main": {
            afterContent: "\n//# sourceMappingURL=custom/url/to/map\n"
         }
    }
})
```